# Need Help in select query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Below are my DB table data

```
id    name  manager_id  hr_id          
 1    abc            0      0           
20    abc1          22     21         
21    abc2          22      1  
22    abc3           1      1   
31    abc4          20     21 
32    abc5          20     21 


function get_child_users($id){
    global $mysqli;
    $q ="SELECT * FROM users where manager_id ='$id' or hr_id ='$id'";
    $sql = $mysqli->query($q);
    echo '<ul>';
    $count = $sql->num_rows;

    if($count > 0 ){
        while($row =  $sql->fetch_array()){
               echo '<li id='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['username'].'';
               echo'</li>';
            }
        echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
```

Above is the function i am creating .

i just want to fetch the data so if looks like

Admin 
  user(have manager_id or hr_id of admin) 
       if has users.suppose it return 2 users 
              then (check the users under those users) ....so on

and finally become a tree that show user hierarchy.

Comment: Try: `$array=json_decode($josn, ture)` and `print_r($array[1]);`

Comment: decode your json, `print_r(json_decode($json)->person);`

Answer (score 0):

You just decode it first then get whatever value you need like so:

```
$decoded_json = json_decode($json);
print_r($decoded_json->person->names[0]);
echo $decoded_json->person->names[0]->first;
```

if you need to loop each person name for example:

```
foreach ($decoded_json->person->names as $key => $each_person_name) {
    echo $each_person_name->first . '<br>';
}
```

Your json format is a bit weird though..

Comment: I need to loop each person name ,username,gender etc.. its something like this

foreach($person  as $person){
 $person['names'][0] ,$person['email'][0],$person['username'][0]

}

this is just and exp that i need. so each first element or each array make a perfect record..Hope you got it

Comment: yea but the problem is your JSON format, it doesn't allow you to loop those person in one go since array are nested in person's property.. so what you need to do is to separate loop for each value.. the above example is for name only but should be same for email and others...

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem

```
function get_child_users($id){
    global $mysqli;
    $q ="SELECT * FROM users where manager_id ='$id' or hr_id ='$id'";
    $sql = $mysqli->query($q);
    $count = $sql->num_rows;
    if($count > 0 ){
        echo '<ul>';
        while($row =  $sql->fetch_array()){
               echo '<li id='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['username'].'';
                          get_child_users($row['id']);
               echo'</li>';
            }
        echo '</ul>';
        }

    }
```